# How to activate a conda environment before running Docker commands

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile, conda

I'm creating a docker image with, inside, a conda environment `myEnv` using a Dockerfile.

I would like, when running the docker image with

```
docker run -it myDockerImage
```

to get to a bash terminal with the environment already activated. I know we can pass variables and commands to `docker run` but I would like it to be done automatically.

I tried adding the following variants to the end of the Dockerfile but nothing seems to work:

```
CMD ["source /root/miniconda/bin/activate myEnv"]
CMD [".", "/root/miniconda/bin/activate", "myEnv"]
CMD ["source /root/miniconda/bin/activate myEnv; /bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Consider adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57595180/832230).

Answer (score 3):

Do this with an `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile.

**src/entrypoint.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# enable conda for this shell
. /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

# activate the environment
conda activate my_environment

# exec the cmd/command in this process, making it pid 1
exec "$@"
```

**src/Dockerfile**

```
# ...
COPY ./entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: This answer seems fine, but also consider this [simpler approach using `ENV PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57595180/) which doesn't require you have an `entryoint.sh` script.

Comment: @Acumenus setting the `PATH` variable might not be enough. According to the [conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) it is not recommended because `conda activate` does more then just setting the `PATH`.

Comment: @Xochipilli Setting `PATH` has been sufficient for me for the past six months. I have had no real-world problem with it whatsoever. Everything essential works in the container. I wouldn't use or recommend this approach outside the container, however.