# Activate and switch Anaconda environment in Dockerfile during build

Tags: python, anaconda, dockerfile, miniconda

I've been trying for hours and can't figure out how to activate and switch anaconda environments in a Dockerfile during the build process

Here's the initial code:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04

# Set user
ENV SETUSER myuser

RUN useradd -m $SETUSER
USER $SETUSER
WORKDIR /home/$SETUSER

# Install Anaconda
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN bash Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
RUN rm Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh

# Set path to conda
ENV CONDA_ENV_NAME mynewenv
RUN /home/$SETUSER/anaconda3/condabin/conda create -q --name $CONDA_ENV_NAME python=3.6 && \
    /home/$SETUSER/anaconda3/condabin/conda clean --yes --all
RUN /home/$SETUSER/anaconda3/condabin/conda activate base #Just for testing anaconda environment
```

At first, anaconda in Docker will complain that the shell is not setup properly, so after the conda create command I added:

```
RUN /home/$SETUSER/anaconda3/condabin/conda init bash
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /home/$SETUSER/.bashrc"
RUN /home/$SETUSER/anaconda3/condabin/conda activate base
```

Running the 3 commands after building the docker image works (i.e. running interactively after calling docker run container-name), but for some reason it does not work when *building* the container. I figured out that the $PATH variable was not being updated during the build, so comparing my $PATH when building and after building.

```
ENV PATH /home/$SETUSER/anaconda3/envs/$CONDA_ENV_NAME/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH /home/$SETUSER/anaconda3/condabin:$PATH
ENV PATH /home/$SETUSER/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
RUN conda init bash
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /home/$SETUSER/.bashrc"
RUN conda activate base
```

Now, the Docker $PATH when building and the $PATH when modified interactively when running the container after-building is the same, but I'm still getting the shell not properly setup error.

*CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
    $ conda init 
Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell
See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.*

Why is this not working???

I've seen that there may be workaround using a miniconda docker template, but I *cannot* use that. How do I create and switch anaconda environment during the Docker building process? Thanks!

Comment: Usually in Docker you don't need a tool like Conda that can manage multiple concurrent isolated software installations: Docker itself provides that isolation.  For Python packages, just run `pip install` in your Dockerfile to install things into the "system" Python (isolated to the image you're building).

Comment: That's all fine, but I need to run a specific versions of python. So I need to create a new anaconda environment for that.

Comment: [Same problem here with solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62674910/3059024)

Comment: Have you tried change this `RUN conda activate base` to `RUN bash -c "conda activate base"`?

Comment: @DavidMaze some packages are only distributed via Anaconda and not available on PyPI

Answer (score 21):

You've got way too many RUN commands in your Dockerfile. It's not just that each RUN creates a new layer in the image. It's also that each RUN command starts a new shell, and `conda activate` applies only to the current shell.

You should combine logical groups of actions into a single RUN command. Use `&&` to combine commands, and `\` to break lines for readability:

```
RUN conda activate <myenv> \
 && conda install <whatever> \
 && ...
```

Keep in mind: at the end of that RUN command, the shell will be gone. So if you want to do something else to that conda environment afterwards, you've got to run `conda activate` again, or else use `-n <myenv>` to put something into an environment without activating it first.

When you start a container from the image, you will also have to call `conda activate` inside the container.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to install the conda environment and run something in it, this approach uses **`ENV PATH`** to launch python indirectly in that conda environment. One can be left wondering if this approach really activates the environment, but so long as the subsequent commands work, and indeed they do, it may not matter.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest
WORKDIR myappdir
COPY environment.yml .
RUN set -x && \
#   apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc && \
    conda install -n base -c defaults conda=4.* && \
    conda env create -n condaenv  # Installs environment.yml && \
    conda clean -a
COPY myapppkg myapppkg
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/condaenv/bin:$PATH
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "myapppkg"]
```

I advise against using `conda run` while it is experimental due to a history of severe bugs such as [this one](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9599) affecting it. Although this particular bug is now fixed, its continued "experimental" nature as shown by `conda run -h` means that it can again break upstream, limiting the trust that one can place in it.

For reference:

- [List of Miniconda Docker tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated)
- List of conda updates by channel: [defaults](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda/files), [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/conda/files)

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tested it with the nvidia image, but [multi-stage Docker builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-an-external-image-as-a-stage) should help you out, which will probably look something like:

```
# get Miniconda docker image to get a installed conda env; WARNING: That image is Debian based
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest AS miniconda


# your Docker commands
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04

# Set user
ENV SETUSER myuser

RUN useradd -m $SETUSER
USER $SETUSER
WORKDIR /home/$SETUSER


# Miniconda: get necessary files from build
COPY --from=miniconda /opt/conda /opt/conda
# Set correct permissions
RUN chown -R $SETUSER: /opt/conda
#   New terminals will have conda active
# If nvidia's Docker image has no .bashrc
# COPY --from=miniconda /home/$SETUSER/.bashrc
# else
RUN echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc

# switch shell sh (default in Linux) to bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# give bash access to Anaconda, then normal anaconda commands, e.g. (-q: quiet, -y: answer yes)
RUN source /home/$SETUSER/.bashrc \
 && conda create -q --name testy \
 && conda activate testy \
 && conda install -y your_package
```

Inspiration from this GitHub issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/89

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the solutions, at last what worked for me was sourcing the conda script after creating the conda env and before calling `conda activate`. Here's an excerpt of my Dockerfile in which I've created three different conda envs and I wanted to install `pip` on each:

```
RUN bash miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
RUN source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda init bash

RUN source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda create --name py37 python=3.7 -y && source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda activate py37 && conda install -c anaconda pip -y && \
    conda create --name py38 python=3.8 -y && source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda activate py38 && conda install -c anaconda pip -y && \
    conda create --name py39 python=3.9 -y && source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda activate py39 && conda install -c anaconda pip -y
```

Without source `conda.sh` calling `conda activate` would result in `conda init <SHELL_NAME>` error.