# RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-installer, conda, setuptools

I have Win 10

When running:

```
conda update conda
```

I encountered this error:

```
RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

Nothing seems to help

I tried to uninstall anaconda and got a successful message but it seems there are some traces of older version that still persist

How can I completely erase all traces of Anaconda installation?

Comment: Is that the entire error output? Where did you run that, in what context?

Comment: There's a similar post in superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1402260/error-when-updating-conda-packages-removeerror-setuptools-is-a-dependency-of and a related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8149

Answer (score 101):

While I still did not find how to cleanly uninstall anaconda, I was able to resolve the error by using the following:

```
conda update --force conda
conda update anaconda
```

and again

```
conda update conda
```

As a result, I got a stable environment with no dependency conflicts. Seems like something within latest conda is too restrictive and update must be forced.

Comment: I didn't need the `--force`. It worked by just doing `conda update conda` and then `conda update anaconda`. Upvote cause it helped me figure it out though.

Comment: The [Anaconda docs](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/keeping-anaconda-date) say updating the anaconda package is not advised, so try `conda update -all` instead.

Comment: I am having a ```ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700):```

Comment: Why does conda break every 2 months?

Comment: I only had to run the first command but I did need the --force

Comment: The modern way is to use `--force-reinstall`

Comment: @Toly your suggestion so far seems ok to me. just that it took quite some times to complete the process. many thanks

Answer (score 8):

I am on a Mac rather than Windows but I was getting the same message. I was able to update by running `conda update setuptools`. It brought conda up-to-date in the process.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Linux Ubuntu 16.04, and it works for me by:

```
conda uninstall setuptools
# This is a must to make it work
conda install setuptools
conda update --force conda
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% sure this is the correct way but it seems I managed to solve it by doing:

```
conda update --force -n base -c defaults conda
```

then again the same command without --force:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Comment: It looks that the `--force` made it work

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble installing scrapy with anaconda using
' conda install -c conda-forge scrapy'

I kept getting the

'Verifying transaction: failed' ' RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.'

error so I tried the mentioned above force install of setup "conda update --force conda" and once that was successful I was able to reapply the scrapy install successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue in a Dockerfile using `continuumio/miniconda3:latest` in which I had the line:

```
RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

To fix it, I simply **appended the `setuptools` requirement**:

```
RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda setuptools
```

There was no need for any other heroics.

Comment: I am dealing apparently with similar circumstances, you would add this line just before activate the env, right?

Comment: '''FROM continuumio/miniconda:latest

WORKDIR /home/reinhold/Documents/webapps/house_market_app/ihm_condaenv

COPY environment.yml ./
COPY app.py ./
COPY boot.sh ./

RUN chmod +x boot.sh

RUN conda update -n base -c defaults

RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

RUN echo "source activate ihm_condaenv" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /home/reinhold/anaconda3/envs/ihm_condaenv/bin:$PATH

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./boot.sh"]'''

Comment: @ReinholdN Yes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57595180/) is how I activate the environment prior to defining an `ENTRYPOINT` which runs `python`.

Answer (score 1):

for macOS for me- I did

1. `conda update --force conda`
2. `conda update anaconda-navigator`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The following should, in most cases fix such problems.

```bash
conda update conda -n base
conda update --all
```

`conda version: 4.13` (check with: `conda --version`)

> **Disclaimer**: *I maintain over 60 conda-forge packages. This snippet has mostly gotten me out of the error so far.*
>
> - GitHub: https://github.com/sugatoray
> - Conda-Forge PRs: [Till Date](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pulls?q=is%3Apr+author%3Asugatoray+sort%3Aupdated-desc+is%3Amerged+)

#### A recommended fail-safe

As a fail safe, please always prefer creating conda environments from environment-specification files: `environment.yml`.

```bash
# update a global environment from a file
conda env update -f ./environment.yml  --prune
```

If you don't already have an environment definition/scpecification file, you can create one as follows. [(source)](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment)

```bash
## Export a platform independent copy of an environment
#  - This will only include packages you installed explicitly.
conda env export --from-history > path/to/environment.yml
```

#### Tips

The conda solver may be slow and you don't have to endure such pain of helplessly waiting when the environment solver finishes and installs the packages.

An easier alternative is to use `mamba` as a drop-in replacement of `conda`. Here's how:

```bash
conda install -n base mamba -c conda-forge
mamba install -n some_env -c some_channel package1 "package2>=2.1.0"
```

To update with `mamba`:

```bash
# Global env + Use file
mamba env update -f ./environment.yml  --prune
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem after updating conda using conda update --force conda.

[image: Solution to problem]

I required to uninstall setuptools to install TA-Lib that had a dependency on setuptools which needed to be fixed.

[image]

After updating conda, you can safely remove setuptools or install the required library.