# How to check if python environment is stable and consistent

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I recently ran into a problem with a Conda environments and I believe I solved it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549872/removeerror-setuptools-is-a-dependency-of-conda-and-cannot-be-removed-from-co). Is there a way to check if what I did actually solved the problem. Can I check if there are still any inconsistencies?

This was meant to be a general question and I did not think it would be dependent on the actual issue I had. It all started when I was having issues with Keras and TensorFlow for GPU in a Conda environment. I came to the conclusion that something was corrupt (I couldn't even run basic Keras commands) and decided to try to update everything and if that didn't fix my issue I would reinstall the packages I needed in that environment. As soon as I tried to update TensorFlow for GPU, the first thing that appeared was:

> The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

Followed by a bunch of packages and version numbers. As I said before I believe I solved the inconsistency issues by force updating Conda but am uncertain how to check if the environment is now consistent.

Comment: Inconsistencies in what? What was the issue?

Comment: @AMC added my specific issue. Inconsistencies in my conda environment. I am uncertain what was causing the inconsistencies as it just listed all the packages installed in my environment and asked me to check them.

Comment: Do you still have the list of packages and versions? Could you just recreate the environment?

Comment: @AMC Thankyou for your help. I have moved past this issue by doing just as you suggested and recreating my environment

Comment: Great, glad to know that worked. Environments sometimes just break like that, especially if you're adding/removing packages after creating them, but starting fresh is usually all that's needed.