# Conda Not Updating - Bisection failure

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install pytorch, that wasn't working.
I was getting this error:
[RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549872/removeerror-setuptools-is-a-dependency-of-conda-and-cannot-be-removed-from-co)

I tried to update conda
`conda update --force conda -vvv`

Stock in some sort of `Bisecting` loop

```py
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (62,71), (97305+311) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 97616
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(721): Bisection failure, new range=(72,81)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (72,76), (97305+248) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 97553
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(734): Bisection success, new range=(72,76)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (72,74), (97305+273) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 97578
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(734): Bisection success, new range=(72,74)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (72,73), (97305+285) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 97590
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(721): Bisection failure, new range=(74,74)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (74,74), (97305+273) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 97578
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(734): Bisection success, new range=(74,74)
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(745): Final peak objective: 74
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(683): Beginning sum minimization
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(700): Initial range (74,1797)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (74,1797), (97578+34091957) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 34189535
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(734): Bisection success, new range=(74,1794)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (74,934), (97578+18355850) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 18453428
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(734): Bisection success, new range=(74,933)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (74,503), (97578+10000493) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 10098071
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(721): Bisection failure, new range=(504,933)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (504,718), (97578+14415055) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 14512633
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(721): Bisection failure, new range=(719,933)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (719,826), (97578+16377195) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 16474773
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(721): Bisection failure, new range=(827,933)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (827,880), (97578+17294005) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 17391583
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(734): Bisection success, new range=(827,880)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (827,853), (97578+16719649) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 16817227
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(721): Bisection failure, new range=(854,880)
TRACE conda.common._logic:minimize(717): Bisection attempt: (854,867), (97578+16953712) clauses
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(607): Invoking SAT with clause count: 17051290
```

conda 4.10.3
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: All I see is a long solve - try using mamba instead

Comment: not familiar, link ?

Comment: [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#readme). You'd install it with `conda install -n base conda-forge::mamba`. Also, note that your Conda seems up-to-date, so it is likely trying to update other packages. [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963979/570918).

Comment: was able to get around it with mamba