# Can't update conda, stuck on `defaults/osx-64::path.py==11.5.0=py37_0`

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to uninstall Anaconda, I try to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182997).

However, I got error below for the first command `conda install anaconda-clean`.

```
RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment
```

Then I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549872/removeerror-setuptools-is-a-dependency-of-conda-and-cannot-be-removed-from-co), but I still couldn't make it when I ran the command `conda update --force conda`. I have tried many times and waited for a very long time, and it always stuck on

```
defaults/osx-64::path.py==11.5.0=py37_0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following the [document](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/#simple-remove) by deleting the anaconda directory with `rm -rf ~/anaconda3`.