# Not able to update conda using terminal

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to update conda using terminal.
via this command
`conda update -n base -c defaults conda`

But, I am getting the below error
`RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment.`

While updating it says that setuptools-68.0.0 will be downloaded, And I think that is the one thing causing error

There's not much mentioned in the error that can help me in solving the error!

Comment: Please add the error in a code block instead of image, so it can be copy pasted and/or searched efficiently.

Comment: Okay I'll post the error in a code block instead an image!

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549872/removeerror-setuptools-is-a-dependency-of-conda-and-cannot-be-removed-from-co)

Comment: @Andrey Thanks that really helped
I don't know why it didn't showup while I was posting the question?!